# Where can I find this hotfix?

Tags: windows-xp, runtime

I've got a problem, and seemly the solution is [a hot fix mentioned here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884538)

The problem is that the link there pointing to location of the hotfix is broken, leading to a search page on MS site. And looking around I figured that the easiest way is to phone Microsoft, but I live in other country.

So, how I fix the problem described in the KB page that I linked?

EDIT: Extra note: I DO have the SP3...
:(

Comment: If you do have SP3, the hotfix will not help.

Comment: I would recommend installing SP3. XP SP2 is End of Support on July 13, 2010 which is just around the corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the page this hotfix is present in Windows XP SP3. So if you install [SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5B33B5A8-5E76-401F-BE08-1E1555D4F3D4&displaylang=en), it should do that job.

Note that you cannot install Windows XP SP3 on a Windows XP RTM. You will need to have minimum SP 1a installed before you can install Windows XP SP3.

```
Date           Time     Version          Size      File name   
--------------------------------------------------------------  
20-Oct-2004    22:59    7.0.2600.2534    57,344    Msvcirt.dll
```

Alternatively if you dont want to install XP SP3, if you can find a PC with XP SP3 already installed, you can copy the dll 'Msvcirt.dll' from C:\Windows\System32 folder, & put that dll in the problem machine's System32 folder.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [other support article Service Pack 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946480) includes this hotfix:

This article lists the problems that are fixed in Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3). Service packs are cumulative. This means that the problems that are fixed in a service pack are also fixed in later service packs. For example, Windows XP SP3 contains all the fixes that are included in Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2).

> 884538
>
> You receive a "This application has
>   requested the Runtime to terminate it
>   in an unusual way" error message when
>   you run a custom Microsoft Visual C++
>   6.0 program in Windows XP
>
> Hotfix